# What if I'm not sure about what area of math a problem lies?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

One student asked me how to solve a problem and the only way of solving it that came to me seems hopeless to find an answers. It occurred to me that I may using a wrong approach to it. How could I ask for help in this case in MO? Could I just post the tittle "What tools should I use for this problem?" and then to describe the problem and my attempt in the body of the question?

ps1: I read in [How do I ask a good question?](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-ask) that "*If your question is about the site itself, ask on our meta-discussion site*". So I did it.

ps2: I didn't write about the problem here because I intend to post in MO for a complete discussion. But if is good, I can write the problem here.

ps3: Once I know how to ask it in MO, I will put a link to the question here. **Edit:** I posted the question: [What tools should I use for this problem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409734/what-tools-should-i-use-for-this-problem)

Comment: Instead of saying "this problem", I strongly suggest giving a hint as to what the problem is in the title. This isn't meant to be clickbait, but something informative, so people can decide whether they want to look at your question or not.

Comment: And saying "this problem in geometry/algebra/number theory" is too vague: the tags will say what area of maths the problem is in. Be a specific as you can given the length constraint. It will also help for people using a search engine to land on the question.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, but I really don't know what area it should be associated. Also I don't know how to properly describe it with a few worlds. Could you see the post and give some clue? Thank you!

Comment: The current title "What tools should I use for this problem?" provides no information about the problem itself, and hence should be improved

Comment: @Diego fair enough! We do have cases where people write generic titles, even when it is clear what is going on, so I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @YCor, I totally agree, but I don't know how to improve. Any suggestion will be welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to MO! Yes, you can try even that title but be prepared that somebody will eventually edit it to something more informative. The main point is to be crystal clear in the statement of the problem. The rest can be edited or added later, if necessary (some people may ask for motivation, etc., but I wouldn't worry too much about it at this stage: if the mathematical content is clear and decent, it will fly).

Comment: thank so much for your help! The question is posted and I tried to follow yours instructions the most.